# Get all URL of Chrome in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome

I start integrating my app with Google Chrome on Android. I want to check my URL already open by Chrome or not, after that I will start Intent to open that URL or switch to Tab already open this URL.

So I have 2 questions:

- Can I get all of URL in current Chrome app?
- Can I switch to tab in Chrome app?

Regards

Comment: check this for chrome custom tabs https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @JineshFrancis I dont use Chrome Tab, I want to use Chrome app

Answer (score 0):

Using content provider you can read these shared datas of chrome.

- content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks
- content://com.android.chrome.browser/searches
- content://com.android.chrome.browser/history
- content://com.android.chrome.browser/combined
- content://com.android.chrome.browser/hierarchy

Accessing data using Content Provider Uri

```
    String URL = "content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks";

    Uri students = Uri.parse(URL);
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(students, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int columnsQty = cursor.getColumnCount();
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                try {
                    sb.append(cursor.getInt(idx));
                }catch (Exception e1){
                    try {
                        sb.append(cursor.getString(idx));
                    }catch (Exception e2){
                        try {
                            sb.append(cursor.getDouble(idx));
                        }catch (Exception e3){
                            try {
                                sb.append(cursor.getBlob(idx));
                            }catch (Exception e4){
                                try {
                                    sb.append(cursor.getFloat(idx));
                                }catch (Exception e5){
                                    try {
                                        sb.append(cursor.getLong(idx));
                                    }catch (Exception e6){
                                        sb.append("Error");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (idx < columnsQty)
                    sb.append(" ").append("( ").append(cursor.getColumnName(idx)).append(" )").append(" | ");
            }
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", cursor.getPosition(),
                    sb.toString()));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

Comment: Can I see example of this data return ?